# $\sum_{(p,q) \in {\mathbb{N}^*}^2 and p \land q =1} \frac{1}{p^2 q^2} = \frac{5}{2}$ proof?

Tags: calculus, summation

Can you give me a very precise demonstration of this result please because it's very difficult for me to understand the demonstration on the pic :(

$$
\sum_{(p,q) \in {\mathbb{N}^*}^2 \text{, } p \land q =1} \frac{1}{p^2 q^2} = \frac{5}{2}
$$

[image]

Thank you ! 
Shadock

Comment: What do you not understand? It is pretty straightforward, as long as you know the sum of $1\over n^2$ and $1\over n^4$

Comment: All the demonstration, i know the sum of 1/n² and $1/n^4$ but i don't understand the demonstration, i have no knowledge about somable familly but just about series...

Comment: And i don't understant the second line and how to go on the third..

Comment: Do you know that : http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Famille_sommable#Produit_dans_les_alg.C3.A8bres_de_Banach ?

Comment: you're using that here implicitly and in both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A$ be the set of all coprimes pairs $(a,b)$ of natural numbers. There is a canonical bijection between $A\times\Bbb N$ and $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N$ given by $((a,b),g)\mapsto(ag,bg)$. This encodes the fact that after dividing a pair of naturals by their gcd one obtains a pair of coprime naturals, and one can go back by just multiplying by the gcd. Therefore, using the substitution $(x,y)=(ga,gb)$, we have

$$\zeta(2)^2=\sum_{(x,y)\in\Bbb N^2}\frac{1}{x^2y^2}=\sum_{\substack{(a,b)\in A \\ g\in\Bbb N}}\frac{1}{(ga)^2(gb)^2}=\sum_{g\in\Bbb N}\frac{1}{g^4}\sum_{(a,b)\in A}\frac{1}{a^2b^2}=\zeta(4)\sum_{(a,b)\in A}\frac{1}{a^2b^2}$$

and hence

$$\sum_{(a,b)\in A}\frac{1}{a^2b^2}=\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)~}. $$

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution itself is not easy to come by yourself, but it is not too hard to follow it.

The main points are:

- first line, you simply rewrite the square of a sum as the sum of all elements
- the real trick is that now that you're summing on $\mathbb{N}^2$, you can rewrite this, as long as you make sure that you still sum on $\mathbb{N}^2$. That's what the author is doing by summing on all the couple $(k,q',p')$ instead of $(q,p)$. You indeed have a bijection between the 2, so you are not modifying the overall sum by summing on that new tuple with that condition.
- the author then factors by $k$ the sum and renames the variables (which has no effect mathematically)
- the last lines are "usual" reseult on series which you seem to know about

If it is the operations on the series that you find hard to follow, you should try on small example to understand exactly what they mean

I hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: So it's possible to transform p' and q' by p and q ... it's really strange for me. Well i've not a really good knowledge on maths, i'm studying chemisry but i've have a lot of maths too and sometimes when I like a problem I try to undersand it even if i've not all the knowledge for that ! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that $p\land q=\gcd(p,q)$.

Since $\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over n^2}$ converges absolutely, we can treat this infinite series without serious consideration.
We have:
$$\begin{align}
\left(\sum_{n\ge1}{1\over n^2}\right)^2
&=\left({1\over1^2}+{1\over2^2}+\cdots\right)\left({1\over1^2}+{1\over2^2}+\cdots\right)
\\&=\sum_{m\ge1,n\ge1}{1\over m^2n^2}
\\&=\sum_{m\ge1,n\ge1}{1\over (m\land n)^4}{1\over (m/(m\land n))^2(n/(m\land n))^2}.
\end{align}$$
In the above equation, $m\land n$ can be any positive integer, and $(m/(m\land n),n/(m\land n))$ can be any pair of positive integers which are coprime. Actually,

> choosing values of $(m/(m\land n),n/(m\land n))$ first and then choosing a value of $m\land n$

is same as

> choosing values of $(m,n)$ at once,

since both determine each other uniquely. For example, (2,3) and 5 determines (10,15), and (10,15) determines (2,3) and 5.

Thus the above equation is:
$$\begin{align}
&=\sum_{a\ge1,b\ge1,a\land b=1 \atop c\ge1}{1\over c^4}{1\over a^2b^2}
\\&=\sum_{c\ge1}{1\over c^4} \cdot \sum_{a\ge1,b\ge1,a\land b=1}{1\over a^2b^2}.
\end{align}$$

We already have:
$$\begin{gather}
\sum{1\over n^2}={\pi^2\over6},\\
\sum{1\over n^4}={\pi^4\over90},
\end{gather}
$$
(these are famous results. You can refer http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem.)

so we get the result.